# javascript comments in razor mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

For `javascript` comments, I usually try to follow something similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799179/javascript-standard-documentation-tool) guidelines. However, the Razor engine seems to throw up when it sees stuff like this in the `cshtml` file:

```
/**
 * This is my function.
 * @param parm1 this is first parameter
 * @param parm2 this is second parameter
 */
```

The @ sign seems to cause parser errors, since that's a special character in Razor. Anyway, I just wondered what other people are doing. I know I could probably use Razor comments and do something like this:

```
@*param parm1 this is first parameter *@
```

But that just feels wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Would it not be better to keep your Javascript completely separate from your Razor?

Comment: I prefer to keep it in the cshtml, since it's part of the view code. For javascript code that is shared across pages, I factor it out to a common file. But for javascript code specific to the page, I like to keep it with the page itself.  Anyway, that's just my philosophy, not saying it's right or wrong.

Comment: @param is definitely going to try to parse that as a variable, which hasn't been defined. You could just modify your docs to use the escaped @. Like: @@param parm1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* 
* This is my function. 
* @@param parm1 this is first parameter 
* @@param parm2 this is second parameter 
*/
```

To write `@` you just need to repeat it `@@` in Razor view.

Comment: I'm not real fond of having to do it this way, but it seems to be the best solution. Thanks for your response.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, escaping `@` with `@@` in `typedef`s prevents IntelliSense from recognizing your type. You have to put them into a separate `.js` file.

Answer (score -1):

The comments for Javascript style / * comment * /  goes under the script section. ie  < script >  /* comment * /  < / script >, the comment style / * comment * / is not valid under razor.
at the HTML code, you could  use < ! -- comment -- >, under the Razor code you could use the @* comment *@

Here is an example:
.... Razor file 
.....
  else
    {
        No Results.
    }

```
@*  razor comment  *@


<!-- html comment -->
<p>

    @if (ViewData["parent"] != null && !HasRole(Site.Enti))
    {

        // another type of comment with Razor

        if (theParent.Parent == null)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Up One Level", "index", "")
        }
        else
        {

             @*   another valid razor comment  *@
            @Html.ActionLink(
                    "Up One Level",
                    "index",
                    new { controller = "", id = theParent.Parent.SchoolGroupId })
        }
    }

    <script>
        /*
            javascript comment
        */
    </script>
```

........
Hope this help